# How do I get new game plus for Arkham Origins?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

So it doesnt say anything about the mode and how to get it. Also Im getting fuzzy noise when all the company names show up? Also in arkham city and maybe asylum

Answer (score 3):

The fuzzy noise it possibly either your TV, or something that actually happens in game.

As for NG+, you can access it once you have beaten the campaign once.